# Doesn't show view from controller even debugger goes inside View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC .net. I am not able to call view from controller. I have debug the flow. It goes to view successfully but doesn't show view on screen.

```
Controller name: Downloads
Action name: MakePayment
Redirect view: Success    //success is view of View/Downloads/Success.cshtml
```

Code: DownloadsController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakePayment(Downloads CCM)
{
     if (true)
     {
          return View("Success");
     }
     else
     {
          return View("Failure");
     }
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Success";
}

<h2>Your transaction has been completed successfully.</h2>
```

Method that I use to call the ActionResult MakePayment. I had use Ajax here because I wanted to call javascript function before form get submit.

```
View: Index.cshtml

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MakePayment", "Downloads", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "payByCreditCard" }))
{
   //submit button
}
```

According to the `return View("Success");`, it should call the view. In fact when I debug the flow, it goes to Success view but doesn't display the view on screen. It keeps old view on screen.

Degug route after success: _ViewStart-->Success.cshtml-->_Layout.cshtml.

Can anybody suggest me if I am missing something?

Comment: have you an `ActionResult` for the Success view?

Comment: What is your old view ? Can you show your complete (relevant) code which returns both the views ? Also do you have this `if(true)` hardcoded ? Then it should return the Success view.

Comment: @user1666620 yes. it make payment using creditcard. I can't post whole code. I just want to redirect to success page when payment get success.

Comment: @Shyju Old View was `Index`.

Comment: Your code should work fine. But i suggest you follow the PRG pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628476/mvc3-prg-pattern-with-search-filters-on-action-method

Comment: @Shyju I have added view code from where I call ActionResult MakePayment. It has Ajax call to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are making an ajax call using `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method, you need to specify where the response (of the ajax call) to be replaced in the DOM. You can specify that using the `UpdateTargetId` property

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MakePayment", "Downloads", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                      UpdateTargetId="YourDivToShowResult"
                                      OnBegin = "payByCreditCard" }))
{
  <div id="YourDivToShowResult"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Since this is an ajax call, It will not do a redirect. Instead,it will update the content of the div (*with Id YourDivToShowResult*) in the same page with response coming back which is the markup returned by Success view.

Also since we are showing a partial page update, you might consider returning a partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakePayment(Downloads CCM)
{
     if (everything is good)
     {
          return PartialView("Success");
     }
     else
     {
          return PartialView("Failure");
     }
}
```

This will return the markup from either of those views without the layout.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to return from MakePayment ActionResult. You said to show div using `UpdateTargetId`. If the payment fail, I want to show failure result. If payment get success, I want to show success message. Can you please suggest me code for `public ActionResult MakePayment(Downloads CCM)` action?

Comment: You already have code for returning either the success or failure view. put whatever message you want to show in those view files.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go to other view you have to redirect the page like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Success", "Downloads");
```

Comment: This is not correct information. You can still return a different view from HttpPost action method ( But redirecting is an ideal solution as it follows PRG pattern)

Comment: I have added view code from where I call ActionResult MakePayment.

Comment: I have also tried by your code. It redirect to Success but doesn't show the Success page on current screen even it route to _ViewStart-->Success.cshtml-->_Layout.cshtml.

Comment: Now because you said that you use ajax, today i just have this kind of problem and my aproach was to give up to use ajax, i found an work around