# System.ArgumentNullException occured in System.Web.Mvc.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where I need to input data and on submit the data gets saved in database. When I checked in database the input is getting saved successfully but I am getting an exception when the page reloads after httppost.
I am getting exception at :

```
  @Html.DropDownList("LineID", new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "LineID", "LineID"), "-- Select LineID --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })
```

controller code to get the dropdownlist values, binding with Db:

```
   [ActionName("DetailsForm")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DetailsForm()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new DetailsViewModel() { dropConfig = floorService.DropDownList().ToList() };
                return View("DetailsForm", model);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("_error");
            }
        }
```

controller code to http post:

```
 [ActionName("DetailsForm")]
        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult DetailsForm(DetailsViewModel model, FormCollection form)
        {

            DetailsConfiguration detailsConfig = new DetailsConfiguration();

            detailsConfig.LineID = Convert.ToString(form["LineID"]);
            //Similary for other fields
            floorService.SaveDetails(detailsConfig);

            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.message = "Success";

            return View("DetailsForm",model);

        }
```

Snapshot of exception:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your view code is using `Model.dropConfig` to build the `SelectList` for your dropdown, and you are not setting the `dropConfig` property value before returning to the view.

Remember, **Http is stateless**. So even though you set the dropConfig property value in the GET action, It won't be available inside your HttpPost action. When you submit your form, it is a totally new request to the server.

You can fix it by loading `dropConfig` property again.

```
model.dropConfig = floorService.DropDownList().ToList();
return View(model);
```

**But ideally you should be following the [P-R-G pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628476/mvc3-prg-pattern-with-search-filters-on-action-method/10628575#10628575)**.

P-R-G stands for **Post**-**Redirect**-**Get**. So when you submit your form to an http post action method, you should return a redirect response and the browser will make a new GET call to that action method.

You can use the `RedirectToAction` method to return a redirect response.

```
floorService.SaveDetails(detailsConfig);
return RedirectToAction("DetailsForm");
```

This will send a 302 response back to the browser with the location header set to the url to the `DetailsForm` action method and the browser will make a new GET request to that.

ViewBag won't work when with redirect response. So you might consider using TempData. TempData can be used to transfer between two requests.

```
TempData["message"] = "Success";
return RedirectToAction("DetailsForm");
```

Now you can read `TempData["message"]` in the DetailsForm action method or the view rendered by that.

For example, you can read it in the view (rendered by DetailsForm GET action method) like this

```
@if (TempData["message"]!=null)
{ 
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button> 
    <strong>Success! </strong>@TempData["message"]
  </div> 
}
```

Comment: I tried    `return RedirectToAction("DetailsForm");`    and it works fine :) But TempData is still not displaying success message for me.

Comment: If you access `TempData["message"]` ,it should work. It should work only for the next request. How are you reading it ?

Comment: i used like how you had mentioned    `TempData["message"] = "Success";`

Comment: That is how you set it. Are you having trouble reading it back ? How are you reading it  in `DetailsForm` ?

Comment: I have added this in DetailsForm      `@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.message))
                    {
                        <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                            <strong>Success! </strong> Request Form Submitted successfully.
                        </div>

                    }`    I used TempData["message"] in place of Viewbag.messgae. Its throws an error.